# static member variable initializing twice

Tags: c++, static, initialization

I'm using my own REGISTER_OBJECT() macro to create a factory full of classes.
It works as expected, except for the initialization of my static std::map variable. If I don't initialize the static std::map in a .cpp file, I'll of course get a unresolved external symbol. But the problem is, I must initialize in the .cpp file that is called first at run time. Otherwise, REGISTER_OBJECT() will get called before the std::map initializer.

```
//std::map MUST be initialized in the .cpp file the compiler calls first.

    std::map<std::string, MyFactory*> Factory::factories; //global init
    REGISTER_OBJECT(MyClass);
```

If I place the std::map initializer in the .cpp file I prefer, REGISTER_OBJECT will be called up to a few times, the std::map will fill accordingly, but then the std::map line hits and the variable is reset.

How on earth can I make sure std::map is initialized before any calls to REGISTER_OBJECT without putting it in another .cpp file. Thanks :)

**SOLUTION**

```
//Factory.cpp
std::map<std::string, MyFactory*>* Factory::factories = NULL;

void Factory::Register(const std::string& name, MyFactory* _class)
{
    if(!factories){ factories = new std::map<std::string, MyFactory*>(); }
    (*factories)[name] = _class;
}
```

Comment: If you're using C++11, maybe [std::call_once](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/call_once) could be useful?

Comment: BTW, if you are calling Register from multiple threads, your solution is not thread safe.

Comment: You have declared your static variable in your header file. Also you need to inform compiler about static variable by defining it in a .cpp file.

Comment: Also see: How do I prevent the “static initialization order fiasco” for my static data members (https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/ctors#static-init-order-on-first-use-members)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could make your factories variable a pointer (initialized to null), and then have your REGISTER_OBJECT macro lazy instantiate it, i.e., set it to new std::map... if it's null.

Answer (score -1):

This article on (essentially) merging a singleton pattern into the class kept my static variable from being created twice (https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/ctors#static-init-order-on-first-use-members)

The basic gist is replace

```
class MyClass {
  // static member gets initialized twice
  static inline int someNumber = randomInt(); 
}
```

... with ...

```
class MyClass {
  // singleton like pattern keeps someNumber from being initialized more than once
  static inline int& someNumber() {
    static int* singletonHack = randomInt();
    return &singletonHack;
  }
}
```

Then access it like this `MyClass::someNumber()`

Comment: in the first case `randomInt()` returns an `int` rvalue, but the second time it assigns a static `int` pointer. In case you actually intend to return a pointer to an rvalue, there will be an UB. If you intend to return a pointer to an already initialized value (global or static), you do not provide a solution, as that value may still be initialized twice.

Comment: It's been a while since I was working on this project, but something very close to this was working for me.  It might just require a minor edit.

Comment: I got a similar problem when trying the inline initialization of a static variable from a function. THe solution that worked for me was to move the initialization from a header file to .cpp (not inline). I suppose that "signle definition rule" just does not hold for inline initialization from functions, though the standard states that the compiler generates only one instance of a static inline variable.